Multiple commands in script step
I have to execute commands multiple times, with different parameters while inside a script. Is there a better way of doing it rather than copy paste the same command and changing the parameters?
- job: Configure_in_QA
  variables:
  - group: development
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: piper-go-official
      path: bin 
    displayName: Configure_Iflow_in_QA
  - script: |
        bin/piper integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration --verbose true --apiServiceKey $(CREDENTIALS) --integrationFlowId "Test_IFlow1_QA" --integrationFlowVersion 'Active' --Key 'LogEnabled' --Value 'true'
        bin/piper integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration --verbose true --apiServiceKey $(CREDENTIALS) --integrationFlowId "Test_IFlow1_QA" --integrationFlowVersion 'Active' --Key 'SNDPRN' --Value '1010101'


Hi Eric, You can use a loop structure within your script to execute the same command with different parameters.


Is there a better way of doing it rather than copy paste the same command and changing the parameters?

I suggest that you can define an object type parameters in Pipeline and then you can use the each expression to loop the object in the parameters to run the script task.
Here is an example:
parameters:
- name: valuelist
  type: object
  default:
  - key: LogEnabled
    value: true
  - key: SNDPRN
    Value : 1010101


jobs:
- job: Configure_in_QA
  variables:
  - group: development
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: piper-go-official
      path: bin 
    displayName: Configure_Iflow_in_QA
  - ${{ each value in parameters.valuelist }}:
    - script: |
          bin/piper integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration --verbose true --apiServiceKey $(CREDENTIALS) --integrationFlowId "Test_IFlow1_QA" --integrationFlowVersion 'Active' --Key '${{value.key}}' --Value '${{value.value}}'

It will run the script task the corresponding number of times according to the number of values ​​in parameters and pass the corresponding parameters value (e.g. format: ${{value.key}} and ${{value.key}} ).
Result:

Later, if you need to add new values to run command, you only need to add the new parameter value in the object parameters, and then an additional script task will be added automatically to run the command.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Loop through parameters
Update:
Based on your comment, you need to read the variable value from a file.
We need to use the script to achieve this requirement. You can refer to the following steps:
Step1: Create a json file to save the data.
For example: test.json
[
  {"key":"LogEnabled","value":"true"},
  {"key":"SNDPRN","value":"1010101"}
]

Step2: We can use script to read the file and loop the value.
readarray -t my_array < <(jq --compact-output '.[]' test.json)

# iterate through the Bash array
for item in "${my_array[@]}"; do
  key=$(jq --raw-output '.key' <<< "$item")
  value=$(jq --raw-output '.value' <<< "$item")
  bin/piper integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration --verbose true --apiServiceKey $(CREDENTIALS) --integrationFlowId "Test_IFlow1_QA" --integrationFlowVersion 'Active' --Key '$key' --Value '$value'
 
done

Pipeline example:
jobs:

- job: Configure_in_QA
  variables:
  - group: development
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: piper-go-official
      path: bin 
    displayName: Configure_Iflow_in_QA
  - script: |
     readarray -t my_array < <(jq --compact-output '.[]' test.json)

      # iterate through the Bash array
      for item in "${my_array[@]}"; do
        key=$(jq --raw-output '.key' <<< "$item")
        value=$(jq --raw-output '.value' <<< "$item")
        bin/piper integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration --verbose true --apiServiceKey $(CREDENTIALS) --integrationFlowId "Test_IFlow1_QA" --integrationFlowVersion 'Active' --Key '$key' --Value '$value'

      done  


Is it possible to have the parameters come from a separate file?

@EricC. I'm afraid paramters can only be hardcoded and cannot be read from a file.

@EricC. Based on your requirement, you need to read the value from a file. You can refer to the updated answer above to get more details. We can read the value from json file and loop the value to run the command in script task.

You can run the script loop-in-a-loop with results and efficiency for Azure DevOps YAML content:
jobs:
- job: Configure_in_QA
  variables:
  - group: development
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: piper-go-official
      path: bin 
    displayName: Configure_Iflow_in_QA
  - script: |
      parameters=(
          "--Key 'LogEnabled' --Value 'true'"
          "--Key 'SNDPRN' --Value '1010101'"
          # Add more parameters here if needed
      )

      for param in "${parameters[@]}"; do
          bin/piper integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration --verbose true --apiServiceKey $(CREDENTIALS) --integrationFlowId "Test_IFlow1_QA" --integrationFlowVersion 'Active' "$param"
      done




Is it possible to store the string parameters into a file, then at runtime read the file and store contents to variable? Then use variable inside the parameters?

Yes You can write the parameters to a file and read them from this file later.
